# mvc4 Razor Ajax Call to show partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Am trying to get a partial view to render with an AJAX call. The following ActionResult is in my base controller which is inherited by all other controllers in the solution:

```
    public ActionResult FileManager()
    {
        return View("_FileManagerPartial");
    }
```

and the folowing code is another partial that sits on the page

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("File Manager", "FileManager", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "dvFilemanagerContainer" });
```

dvFilemanagerContainer is a div in the layout view and the partial view "_FileManagerPartial.cshtml" is in the shared views folder.

When I click the link for the ajax call, instead of loading the intended partial view it loads a duplicate of the page into the div.

Any ideas?

**Edit**
PartialView contents its currently just the following

```
<div id="dvFilemanagerWrapper">
File Manager
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your complete partial view `_FileManagerPartial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was to do with how my RouteConfig was handling the call. Have created a new MapRoute to point it to the right place and is now working. Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 2):

change your controller to

```
public PartialViewResult FileManager()
{
    return PartialView("_FileManagerPartial");
}
```

Comment: still just loads a duplicate of the page.

Comment: when you created the partial view you chose the option to create it as partial right?  in your folder structure do you see _FileManagerPartial.cshtml?

Comment: yes was created as a partial in the "Shared" folder. If I put a break point the FileManager ActionResult/PartialViewResult it doesn't get hit so it looks like the Ajax call is getting to the code.

Answer (score 1):

In View add this line, so that with partial view, the master layout is not rendered, only partial view is rendered:

```
@{

Layout = null;

}

<div id="dvFilemanagerWrapper">
File Manager
</div>
```